# Receive one Byte from serial port in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I know this has probably been asked before but for my problem I cannot find a solution.
I need a function `receive(int recv)` that I call in a loop and that receives one Byte.
I have set up my serial port so far (termios.h) and am able to receive using `read()`
However I can only receive the whole buffer of the port. So `read(fd, recv, 255);` always returns multiple bytes.
What I would need is a Buffer in which I receive bytes and when `receive(int recv)` is called it always gives the first byte of this buffer.
How would such a buffer look like? I would gladly appreciate any help on this one!
Thanks!

Comment: From your code, I /think/ you're trying to read an integer from the serial port - is this correct? At the moment, it looks like you're calling `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)` with `int recv` as the second parameter, which is badly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
// ...
char buf[1];
read(fd, &buf, 1);
// ...
```

Comment: I was thinking of that, but then again, doesn't the buffer overflow  easily if it's is only one byte in size?

Comment: No. The function writes 1 byte into it if there is 1 byte available, otherwise 0. That's it. It can only overflow if you make it smaller than the value you pass to `read()`, but as you don't do so, nothing will and can happen.